# Chrome on-line PDF calculation fails

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I have a weird situation with Chrome 66.0.3359.181 64-bit and an on-line PDF file (version 1.6, Acrobat 7.x).

All fields are calculated correctly with Acrobat Reader DC 2018.011.20040, but not in Chrome. Any help appreciated how I could modify the file so that it is calculated correctly.

The file in question: http://tietoala.fi/rauta/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/matkalasku_2018.pdf
This is in Finnish, should that matter. In Finnish, the decimal separator is comma "," and not dot ".". This might be at least partly the reason. This form is intended for anyone claiming travel compensation.

Let's take for example the € field for "Taksi". If I put there "20", it turns correctly out "20,00 €" for both that field and total calculation. But, if I put "20,50", it turns out "20,50 €" correctly in the field, but total calc is "20050,00 €" that is obviously incorrect.

Calculation for the total is set to "Value is the sum(+) of the following fields:" and then picked the corresponding two fields. It is of format "Number" with 2 decimal places, separator style "1234,56" (as in Finnish), and currency symbol "€". The field is not locked. This field is not validated. There is no action.

Additionally, when filling in "Kilometrikorvaus", inserting "2" into km and "2" into á€, it is calculated correctly as 4,00 €. But, if used "0,44" as the á€, the total says "nan €". Here the fields are as described above, but calculation is as follows:

```
var f1 = this.getField("km1");
var f2 = this.getField("a5");
if ( f1.value*f2.value != 0 )
  event.value = f1.value * f2.value;
else
  event.value = "";
```

I would appreciate any help figuring out how to fix my form. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't use Acrobat to prototype forms that you want to run in other viewers. Acrobat and Reader are your best case scenario in that it has the most support for JavaScript. All others... I repeat... all others... have less support including Adobe's own mobile Reader.

Long answer: Not all PDF Viewers consume JavaScript in the same way as Acrobat and most don't implement the full set of objects, events, and properties as Acrobat. For example, Chrome doesn't execute the format scripts that are in some of your fields. My guess is that Chrome is interpreting the numbers with commas in them as strings.

By setting the field to be numeric and the separator style to use a comma rather than a decimal point, Acrobat automatically adds some JavaScript to the field that forces it to return a number.

[image]

Chrome isn't executing that built-in script so it's misinterpreting the value of the field. Try adding some code to your script that parses the value of the field to a Number first, then do the math. It will be more verbose but hen will run the same in Acrobat and Chrome.